# Restart EC2 instance maintaining the IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

If I restart an Amazon EC2 instance the IP will be reseted, right? Is there a way to use the same IP I'm using right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: Elastic IPs.

From the FAQ:  Elastic IP addresses are static IP addresses designed for dynamic cloud computing. An Elastic IP address is associated with your account not a particular instance, and you control that address until you choose to explicitly release it. Unlike traditional static IP addresses, **Elastic IP addresses allow you to mask instance manually or programmatically remapping your public IP addresses to any instance in your account**.